# Kinect V2 "Body Index" tracking stopped working

Tags: windows, kinect, kinect-sdk

I am in the proccess of developing a kinect v2 desktop app for an RnD project.
Roughly a month ago I was provided with the Kinect Sensor, I connected it to a USB 3.0 port(motherboard) Installed the SDK and everything was working properly, depth, color, body index tracking (skeleton joints) etc. After I confirmed everything was working, I put the project on pause.

So yesterday I decided to continue working on the project, when I realised the "Body Tracking" feature was not working, not in Kinect Studio not even in the examples provided.

I uninstalled/reinstalled drivers and the Kinect SDK, I tried different USB ports, nothing seems to fix this issue. I scoured Google for possible solutions, I have found nothing.

I am running Windows 10, I cannot recall If during these 30 days Windows installed some sort of update that maybe messed up drivers.

Just to clarify the sensor appears to be working, when I open the Kinect Studio, the only feature that does not work is the body index one.

Also when I run the "Kinect v2 Configuration Verifier" everything is "Green" except the "USB controller" section which is "Orange" (although I believe it was always like this, even when it was working not 100% sure).

Can anyone help me solve this issue?

Cheers!

Comment: Can you specify the processor, ram and other configuration?

Answer (score 0):

So I solved the issue, and I am ashamed. It seems that I was keeping the appropriate distance beetween myself and the kinect. When I moved a couple of meters back, the bone index worked. So to anyone having this problem, make sure you are standing at least 1.5 meters away from the Kinect sensor